# Is there any support for collapsing all function nodes within the F# editor?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Is there any support for collapsing all function nodes in Visual Studio for the F# editor?

In C#, I often use:

```
Ctrl + M + O
```

or...

```
Ctrl + M + L
```

Comment: While there are corner cases where such a feature can be useful, in general I consider it a code smell whenever I find myself wanting to do that.

Comment: Ctrl M L will work will work directly after you turn on outlining via Ctrl M O (Ctrl M P to turn off to get to such a state); It seems it's not as polished an impl. I'm pretty sure I'm with Mark though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but the [Visual F# Power Tools](https://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools) extension adds [outlining support](https://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/outlining.html) along with a bunch of other useful goodies.

Once installed, the usual outlining shortcuts seem to work as expected.

Comment: I have it installed. But I hate using the mouse just to collapse one function at a time. Do I have to use a mouse to collapse?

Comment: All [keyboard shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s.aspx) except 'Collapse to Definitions' (CTRL + M + O) work for me in VS 2015. I suspect it doesn't have much of an idea what a definition should be for F#.